# Is there an advantage with Code First (DbContext model) vs EDMX files?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Our group has a DBA that manages all the databases. We started to use Code First and it's working okay.  Now we have suggestions that we should be using a database first approach but as far as I am aware this requires us to do mapping in a diagram and we cannot use the Fluent API.

We're happy with the idea of POCO classes so would it be best for us to just continue with Code First or is there a particular advantage (other than stored procedure use) with using EDMX files and the traditional way of working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main advantage is flexibility, avoid code-generation and acquire more control over how the things are made behind the scenes.

As you define the mappings in code, you've more power in terms of mapping strategies, tweaking and configuration.

In summary: your domain won't be database-driven: you've your domain model and it's the database who needs to fit it. For me, this is how should be a serious domain using a serious OR/M. OR/M makes more possible to build true object-oriented domains while they handle the pain of interoperate with a very different world, the relational model.

If you really want to have a platform-independent, neutral domain model, Code-First is the way to go.

Maybe I'm biased, but my opinion is serious, medium-to-large or great projects should start and go with Code-First. Code generation and the EDMX paradigm and this kind of sugar works if your domain isn't that complex. Once it gets complex, you need to work on your own data and domain strategies.

Comment: I honestly think the DDD community is too anal, e.g. "very different world, the relational model". it is not _that_ different, I would even bet money that atleast 80% of your entities are pure 1-1 mappings from class to table w/o any fancy modifications at all.. and true platform independence is an illusion, there will always be differences in how some queries execute and behave and what optimizations works best depending on provider. in a big real world project you are very likely to end up with crapload of compromizes anyway, e.g. handwritten SQL in some places.

Comment: @Matias - I am also starting to think the same way as you. However how do you handle the case where for example I'm using Code First and I want to add a column to a class. Now if I do this and the DBA also adds a column but uses the wrong name what will happen then. Will it give me an error when I next access the database and how can I find the bug if the scenario is a bit more complex?

Comment: @RogerAlsing You're guessing too much. At least my domain models, either using NHibernate or Entity Framework, tend to implement everything using pure OOP and I prefer the pain of trying to adapt the mappings to SQL/Relational to the domain, rather than doing the inverse process.

Comment: @Marilou **Column not found!**. If you have good logging, most of the times EF is very explicit when it comes to identify a bugged mapping. No problem here :)

Comment: @RogerAlsing In addition, it's true: there're a lot of domain objects having the same properties as the relational entity. Why not? This isn't the difference of relational an OOP models: it's how the relations are performed. If you do it rightly, in your domain model will you ever find a JOIN? No: you'll have a collection. And so on. I don't know what's saying the DDD community. I'm talking about my own way of understanding the problem.

Comment: I know how it works, I was one of the two main devs of NPersist ORM back in the day when it was alive, I'm just objecting to the idea of "if you do code first everything will be soo much better" attitude that exists in the DDD community. it's never that simple.. in a perfect naive world, code first works fine.. but may times you might have to hand roll hardcore SQL optimizations and conform to DB design considerations because of performance etc.

Comment: @RogerAlsing You're wrong. I've never done a project using EDMX. And I'm more friend of NHibernate. It's my own conviction, even before I knew about DDD (I know is a long time concept, but I'm too young yet). I mean, in my case, I was doing something like DDD (and I keep doing my own point of view of what's a domain model) before my discovery, and in order to avoid calling "Matias Domain Model", I prefer to stick with the community and follow the naming conventions for identifying what's DDD and a domain model :D

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I've never said you've done models using EDMX, and what part of my statement is wrong? you mean you don't have to resort to hand written SQL or bulk inserts etc in big real world projects?

Comment: @RogerAlsing I mention that in order to make you understand I'm not biased with _DDD trend_ these days. That's it! And yes, I've done pure SQL without OR/M, and it's still useful, of course :)